# Left Join with subquery returns Null

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am applying `Left Join` with `Sub query & where clause`

It seems fine no syntax error but the columns I am selecting from that sub query always returns me `Null`. I have executed the same part in my `SQL` section, it gives me record. Kindly have a look on the query and let me know if any thing is possible or if question is not clear.

```
SELECT alt.userId, u.name, t.name AS teamName, alt.startDateTime, v.name AS     villageName, c.name AS clusterName, startLat, startLong, latlng.lat, latlng.long 
FROM activity_log_tim AS alt 
JOIN user AS u ON u.userId = alt.userId
JOIN team_members AS tm ON tm.memberId = u.userId
JOIN team AS t ON t.teamId = tm.teamId
JOIN village AS v ON v.villageId = alt.villageId
JOIN cluster_villages AS cv ON cv.villageId = v.villageId
JOIN cluster AS c ON c.clusterId = cv.clusterId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT lat, long,dateTime, scheduleId FROM activity_log_gps LIMIT 1) AS latlng ON latlng.scheduleId = alt.scheduleId
WHERE DATE(alt.startDateTime) = '2015-09-05' AND DATE(alt.endDateTime) = '0000-00-00' GROUP BY alt.userId ORDER BY latlng.dateTime DESC
```

Comment: What should the inner select do?

Comment: You are returning an arbitrary record from `activit_log_gps` and then complaining that sometimes there is no match?  Using `limit` without an `order by` is suspect.  Then doing a `join` on one of the columns seems misguided.

Comment: The subquery store the user lat, long after every min but I need only their last one.@juergend d

Answer (score 0):

Well it's supposed to since you are performing a `LEFT JOIN` which produces `NULL` if no match occurs. So either you can perform a `INNER JOIN` or use a `COALESCE` function like below

```
   SELECT alt.userId, u.name, 
t.name AS teamName, 
alt.startDateTime, 
v.name AS     
villageName, 
c.name AS clusterName, 
startLat, 
startLong, 
COALESCE(latlng.lat, 23), //Notice the use of COALESCE. If null will return 23 as default 
COALESCE(latlng.long, 32)
```